# Excel changing the auto-increment for rows when dragging

Tags: excel, auto-increment

Sorry if this is trivial.
I need to create 2 rows out of every row:

> =A1
>   =A1
>   =A2
>   =A2

But when i drag this down i get:

> =A1
>   =A1
>   =A2
>   =A2
>   =A5
>   =A5
>   =A6
>   =A6

What i need to get of course is:

> =A1
>   =A1
>   =A2
>   =A2
>   =A3
>   =A3
>   =A4
>   =A4

I thought to get there by using OFFSET and a negative row number but i wasn't able to work it out so far.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `INDEX` and `ROW` combination. Enter:

```
=INDEX(A:A,ROW(2:2)/2)
```

And drag down.

You can also drag right if you the row contains more columns.